# Google Sheets: Lookup last matching values but with expanding rows

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas

I'm using a dynamic, expanding sheet containing form responses. Search keys are in A2:A, responses are in the Responses sheet. So,

To get an expanding VLOOKUP, I do:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Responses!A2:C, 3, 0))`

To get the last matching value (for example, latest timestamp) of a repeating search key, I use a combination of FILTER, MAX, and INDEX like so:

`=INDEX('Responses'!C2:C, MAX(FILTER(ROW('Follow-up Responses'!A2:A), 'Responses'!A2:A=A2)))`

And this works by just dragging it down, but is there a way to make this expanding in an ARRAYFORMULA function? I tried modifiying it as ranges but all I get is one row. My form responses are added quickly so there may come a time where the formula has not been dragged down to the most current.

Thanks!

Comment: You can sort your data descending on timestamp and then use vlookup. As vlookup returns only the first match found, you should have the last matching value based on timestamp (which will be the first match in vlookup, because of the sorting). If you need help, please share a copy of your spreadsheet.

Comment: That's a great workaround when using timestamps. All I had to do is do a QUERY and IMPORTRANGE combo to sort it to descending. Thanks! I have a question though, what would you do if there's no sortable column like Timestamps, and you'd want to get the latest/last row of a search key?

Answer (score 0):

Sample formula with lookup of last value using row:

`=VLOOKUP(D2 ; SORT(FILTER({$A:$B\ROW($A:$A)};$A:$A<>"");3;0) ; 2;)`

- `D2` -- search value
- `A:B` -- initial
- `row(A:A)` -- any row for getting last values in the top.